# my app could not send a message from my real device to emulator! What is goes wrong? is needed to more settings?

Tags: android, client-server, emulation

i am new by android.I have started work with a simple chat app. I wrote a short code by `UDP` socket one for client and one for server.Now i have some issues at connectivity android real device which client app installed on it , and emulator device which server app run on it.
Client app is a simple code which must set IP for connection to emulator and also has a EditText for sending a message.(I at this point set 10.0.2.2 or 10.0.2.15. But my app could not send a message from my real device to emulator! What is goes wrong? is needed to more settings?)
Server app has only a `textView` for getting and showing recived message.
here is Client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class ClienttextchatActivity extends Activity 
{
       private String udpMsg=null;
       Handler hand=new Handler();
       EditText edtSetIp=null , edtText=null;
       Button btnSetIp=null , btnSend=null;
      static String ip=null;
       static final String LOG_TAG = "UdpStream";    
       static final int PORT = 8888;     
       static final int BUF_SIZE=4096;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        edtText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtText);
        edtSetIp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtSetIp);
        btnSetIp=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSetIp);
        btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
        btnSetIp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                ip=edtSetIp.getText().toString(); 
            }
        });
        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {

                  Thread mythread=new Thread(new th1() );
                  mythread.start();


            }
        });

    }
   //#############################################


   public class th1 implements Runnable
    {           
        public void run() 
        {                   

            udpMsg  =edtText.getText().toString();  

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,udpMsg);
            DatagramSocket ds = null;

            try 
            {                               
                        ds = new DatagramSocket();
                        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"address server address created.");
                        DatagramPacket dp;
                        dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, PORT);
                        ds.send(dp);        
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,"packet send.");  
            } 
            catch (SocketException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (UnknownHostException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally 
            {
                if (ds != null) 
                {
                    ds.close();
                }
            }

        }//end run
    }//end class th
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure emulator is started, then in ADB shell, type this command, it will show ip address of emulator.

```
adb shell
ifconfig etho
```

[image: terminal]